# utl_file need to write multiple query results to same line for each acct num returned

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE RegFile_PrevDay_Gen(x_return_status  OUT   VARCHAR2,
                                                in_share_dir     IN    VARCHAR2)
IS
  output_file_name  VARCHAR2(60);
  output_file_handle utl_file.file_type; 
  sameday_cust      varchar2(20) ;
  previousday_cust  varchar2(20) ;
  achsameday_cust   varchar2(20) ;
  v_service         kndtexe.texe_cnfuncid%type;
  v_subservice      kndtexe.texe_cnsubser%type;
  v_map             kndtmap.tmap_cndesc%type;
  bank_num          varchar2(10);
  account_num       varchar2(10);

  CURSOR bankid_account IS 
    SELECT DISTINCT to_char(TEXE_CNNETNAM,'FM00') bank_num 
                    ,to_char(TEXE_CNASUPRO, 'FM0000000000') account_num
                    , 'N' previousday_cust 
                    , 'N' sameday_cust
                    , 'N' achsameday_cust
                    ,(TEXE_CNFUNCID) v_service
                    ,(TEXE_CNSUBSER) v_subservice
                    ,(TMAP_CNDESC) v_map
      FROM KNDTEXE,
           KNDTMAP,
           KNDTSCM,
           KNDTCTC
      WHERE KNDTEXE.TEXE_CNCCLIPU = KNDTSCM.TSCM_CNCONTRA
        AND KNDTEXE.TEXE_CNFUNCID = KNDTSCM.TSCM_CNSERVIC
        AND KNDTEXE.TEXE_CNSUBSER = KNDTSCM.TSCM_CNSUBSER
        AND KNDTSCM.TSCM_CNMAPCO = KNDTMAP.TMAP_CNMAPCO
        AND TEXE_CNESTADO IN ('01')
        AND TEXE_CNNETNAM <> '(null)'
        AND ( (KNDTEXE.TEXE_CNFUNCID = '3050' AND KNDTEXE.TEXE_CNSUBSER = 'I1') OR 
              (KNDTEXE.TEXE_CNFUNCID = '3050' AND KNDTEXE.TEXE_CNSUBSER = 'I2') OR
              (KNDTEXE.TEXE_CNFUNCID = '3050' AND KNDTEXE.TEXE_CNSUBSER = 'I3') OR
              (kndtexe.texe_cnfuncid = '3050' and kndtexe.texe_cnsubser = 'I4') OR
              (kndtexe.texe_cnfuncid = '3050' and kndtexe.texe_cnsubser = 'I5') OR
              (KNDTEXE.TEXE_CNFUNCID = '3050' AND KNDTEXE.TEXE_CNSUBSER = 'I6') OR
              (KNDTEXE.TEXE_CNFUNCID = '3070' AND KNDTEXE.TEXE_CNSUBSER = 'D1') OR
              (KNDTEXE.TEXE_CNFUNCID = '3070' AND KNDTEXE.TEXE_CNSUBSER = 'D2') ) 
      ORDER BY account_num;
BEGIN
  x_return_status:='FAIL';

  output_file_name := 'PrevDayRegistryFile_'||to_char(systimestamp,'dd-mm-yyyyhh24-mi-ss.FF')||'.txt';
  output_file_handle := utl_file.fopen(in_share_dir,output_file_name,'W');

  OPEN bankid_account;  

  LOOP
    FETCH bankid_account
      INTO bank_num, account_num, previousday_cust, sameday_cust, achsameday_cust, v_service, v_subservice, v_map;
    EXIT WHEN bankid_account%notfound;

    IF (v_service = '3050' AND v_subservice = 'I1') OR
       (v_service = '3050' and v_subservice = 'I3') OR
       (v_service = '3050' and v_subservice = 'I4') OR
       (v_service = '3050' and v_subservice = 'I5') OR
       (v_service = '3070' and v_subservice = 'D1') OR
       (v_service = '3070' and v_subservice = 'D2')
    THEN 
      previousday_cust := 'Y';
    END IF;         

    commit;

    UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE (output_file_handle, bank_num || '|' || account_num || '|' || previousday_cust || '|');

    IF (v_service = '3050' and v_subservice = 'I2') OR
       (v_service = '3050' and v_subservice = 'I6')
    THEN
      sameday_cust := 'Y';
    END IF;

    commit;

    UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE (output_file_handle, bank_num || '|' || account_num || '|' || sameday_cust || '|');

    IF (v_service = '3050' AND v_subservice = 'I2' and v_map = 'SameDay ACH Only') OR
       (v_service = '3050' and v_subservice = 'I2' and v_map = 'SameDay ALL') OR
       (v_service = '3050' AND v_subservice = 'I6' and v_map = 'SameDay ACH Only' ) OR
       (v_service = '3050' AND v_subservice = 'I6' and v_map = 'SameDay ALL')
    THEN
      achsameday_cust := 'Y'; 
    END IF;

    commit;

    UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE (output_file_handle, bank_num || '|' || account_num || '|' || achsameday_cust || '|'); 

    dbms_output.put_line (bank_num ||' '|| account_num ||' '|| previousday_cust ||' '|| sameday_cust ||' '|| achsameday_cust);  

    UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE (output_file_handle, bank_num || '|' || account_num || '|' || previousday_cust || '|' || sameday_cust || '|' || achsameday_cust);
  END LOOP; 

  CLOSE bankid_account;

  utl_file.fclose(output_file_handle);
  x_return_status:='SUCCESS';
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    x_return_status :='FAIL:No Data Found';
    utl_file.fclose(output_file_handle);                  
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    x_return_status :='FAIL:When Others:'||SQLERRM;
    utl_file.fclose(output_file_handle);
END;
```

the procedure needs to write the output from the 3 queries that assigns Y or N from prevday, sameday, and achsameday to a single line for each account#(there may be more than one acct# assigned)...so if the query returns prevday Y and sameday Y then output needs to look like 21||1234567||Y||Y|| instead of 21||12344567||Y||N and a second line of 21||1234567||N||Y. 
Please help!

The output is as below:

Connecting to the database service-UAT.

```
210000053104YNN
210000053104NYN
```

So as an output to the file i need instead of the above-
210000053104YYN for all the iterations that are displaying multiple times per the loop.

```
480000126547NYN
480000126547YNN
460000240508YNN
460000240508NYN
210000264241YNN
770000280254YNN
770000280254NYN
770001703188NYN
770004641663YNN
770004641663NYN
770007013884NYN
770007013884YNN
770007015909NYN
770007015909YNN
770007033427YNN
770007048939YNN
770007048939NYN
770007049560YNN
770007049579NYN
770007049579YNN
770007169108NYN
770007169108YNN
770007287798YNN
770007964390YNN
770007964390NYN
210008000582YNN
210008007129YNN
210008007129NYN
770008095612YNN
770008095612NYN
770008100667NYN
770008100667YNN
```

Comment: I don't quite follow... you have three `utl_file.put_line` calls and you only want one line to be written? So can't you just remove the first two calls? Or are you talking about peeking ahead and back at next/previous iterations of the cursor loop? Some sample data, current and expected output would help clarify what you're trying to do.

Comment: one line per acct#...lets say acct# 12345678 is prevday_cust = 'Y' and sameday_cust = 'Y' then i want result on utl_file to be 21 12345678 Y Y instead of 21 12345678 Y N and 21 12345678 N Y. Here is a sample of the output: 210000053104YNN
                  210000053104NYN so instead of tis i need it to be like 210000053104YYN

Comment: Please put new information into the question as an edit so it can be formatted sensibly. I'm still not sure if you're trying to merge values from different iterations of the loop. Including the underlying data that leads to that result will clarify what is happening and what you want, but please try to expand your explanation too.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, here are is my assumption to get to what I think you are looking for:
1. There can be multiple lines per bank account number, with varying results, and you want to capture all Y's that override the N's.

If this is true, then I'd set a save record to keep track of which bank acct you are on, and when this changes, put_line the output and reset the variables to the current record (since this is the new account).

As you loop through a single account, if the value changes to Y, save it, otherwise leave it as is, since you're presetting them to N.

Comment: Yes and the code where it is reset is the if-then part and when i write it out with utl_file i want each acct# to display the corresponding Y or N as one record!

Comment: But you would only output it when the banknum changed, and I don't see that logic in there - only the if-then logic to set the flags. The put_line should only occur when the banknum changes (comparing to a variable like saved_banknum), and the data would be what was saved - then reset and check again.

Comment: The banknum, acctnum are what the cursor returns and don't change. Within each of those returns i need to set the flags to the sameday, prevday, and achsameday records.

Comment: You could also just do it within the cursor with case statements, setting the flags by evaluating each of those values. It would look messy, but it could get the job done, such as: case when (your if code) then Y else N end flagname and then just concatenate them and output the line once for each cursor loop.

Comment: would the case statement go within the where clause? since i am doing a join on three tables i am having a hard time figuring out the logistics for the select statement.

Comment: Help! Let me try to word this better. In this scenario, for every account_number there will be services (eg.3050) and subservices (eg. 'I1','D1'). I1 would/could be prevday, D1 would/could be sameday. I need output for unique acct#s(one line per acct) with the appropriate flags marked as either 'Y' or 'N'. Can someone advise me on a select subquery that might get me going on this?